# KO Template with Foreach If condition causing afterAdd not to fire

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

In the example below you'll see that doSomething never fires.  If you remove the `if: Comments` from the templating binding doSomething will fire as expected.  Does anyone know what is happening to cause this? This also occurs while using the `data` attribute on the template binding handler.

I am currently using Knockout 2.2.1.  jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YADzx/2/

```
<div data-bind="template: { if: Comments, name: 'comments' }"></div>

<script type="tmpl" id="comments">
    <div data-bind="foreach: { data: Comments, afterAdd: $root.doSomething }">
        <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    </div>
</script>
<script>
var vm = {
    Comments: ko.observableArray([{name:'hey'}]),
    doSomething: function (element, index, data) {
        $(element).addClass('wow');
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);
vm.Comments.push({name:'foo'});
vm.Comments.push({name:'bar'});
</script>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `if` condition on the `template` binding causes it to update whenever `Comments` changes. Knockout will then re-render the entire template and the previous state of the `foreach` binding is lost.

There are a few ways to work around this depending on what side-effects you want or don't want.

1. Remove the `if` option. Your code will all still work, but you'll have the `<div>` with the `foreach` binding in your HTML. So this isn't a good option if it messes up your layout.
2. Split up the `if` from the `template` and use another element (or comment-syntax) with the `if` binding. This will work as long as you're using version 2.2.0 or higher of Knockout.

   ```
   <script type="tmpl" id="comments">
       <!--ko if: Comments-->
       <div data-bind="foreach: { data: Comments, afterAdd: $root.doSomething }">
           <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
       </div>
       <!--/ko-->
   </script>
   ```
3. Instead of using the `if` binding, use the `visible` binding, which hides the current element and does not re-render.

   ```
   <script type="tmpl" id="comments">
       <div data-bind="visible: Comments, foreach: { data: Comments, afterAdd: $root.doSomething }">
           <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
       </div>
   </script>
   ```

One thing to consider, though, is that an `observableArray` won't generally contain a falsy value. That's because in JavaScript, an empty array is still truthy. If you want to test for an empty array, you'll need to change from `if: Comments` to `if: Comments().length`.

Comment: Thank you so much, wish I could vote this up more.. spent hours trying to figure this out!